# Create fluid triangle with CSS

Tags: css, geometry

I want to create this triangle in CSS.
http://acceptatie.foursites.nl/foursites/vierkant.jpg

But it must be a fluid triangle. How can i make this I try with skewY. But than the triangle is broken at the to of the element.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Comment: the image you posted isn't a triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using borders to make the triangle you can use transform to rotate a div and just hide the overflow of the parent element.

If use transform instead of borders you can have box shadow on the div to :)

Tranform code for rotating a div

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(357deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(357deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(357deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(357deg);
```

and as i said just hide the overflow on the parent element, in your case the body tag

```
overflow: hidden;
```

But here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy5Dz/1/)

Hope you can use it.